# How to write different datasets in parallel to disk?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

If I have a list of `Dataset` which I map over to write data to disk, Spark writes them one at a time. Is there a way to write them to disk asynchronously?

Comment: You have a normal list or an `RDD[Dataset]`?

Comment: @cricket_007 nested distributed structures are forbidden in Spark and it doesn't make sense. Don't forget that a Dataset is an RDD under the hood. Now that said, and like I have commented on the answer below, running multiple parallel jobs in parallel by design isn't possible. It's one of the limitations of distributed systems. If a machine T1 is busy doing a job J1 it can't process J2 at the same time and so one... Scheduling problems and this problem is NP-complet and can't be optimized.

Comment: @eliasah Right :) Was just asking for clarification like how a list of `Dataset` was even made

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah no problem ! :-) I was just wondering how come the answer has been upvoted. :-/

Comment: If you parallelize your write statements in the driver, then Spark will try to execute those in parallel as well.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean something like `List<Dataset<Row>> `, so just a collection of datasets representing different query plans.  If you have multiple datasets, potentially writing to different data stores, and cluster space to spare, how do you execute the parallel operations...for lack of a better word... in parallel?  It would be additive, not multiplicative.  I also have this question.